# Checking a users permissions in django template

Tags: django, permissions

Still having problems, I saw the other posts.  and the post here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.11/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates

So I am doing this:

```
    {% for trn in trainee %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ trn.first_name }} {{ trn.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ trn.institution }}</td>
        <td>{{ trn.contact_phone }}</td>
        <td>{{ trn.contact_email }}</td>
        <td>{{ trn.trained_date }}</td>
        {% if perms.django_apo.training.delete_trainee %}
          <td> BUTTON </td>
        {% else %}
          <td> NA </td>
        {% endif %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

This is what the permissions look like for said person:
[image]

Yet, it comes up with NA everytime.  What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `{% if perms.django_apo_training.can_delete %}`? So the name of the model as one part, and `can_delete` instead of `delete_trainee`?

Comment: Shouldn't be `django_app` instead of `django_apo`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you are exactly right, that fixed it.